# Close jQuery responsive menu onclick of menu item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple open/close responsive menu that uses jQuery. The menu works just fine but the website I'm using it on is a simple single page site with different sections. My problem is the menu opens and closes when the user clicks the menu handle and I'd like it to close when the user clicks on a menu item also. I have very little experience in jQuery so I need help solving this problem.

The HTML:

```
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href="#home"><li>home</li></a>
      <a href="#about"><li>about</li></a>
      <a href="#contact"><li>contact</li></a>
    </ul>
    <div class="handle">Menu</div>
  </nav>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('.handle').on('click', function(){
  $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the toggleClass to just toggle to hide the elements. To get the behavior you'd like, change your jQuery selector to:

```
$('.handle, nav ul a').on('click', function(){
  $('nav ul').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this:

```
$('.handle').on('click', function(){
  $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
});
$('nav ul a').on("click", function(){
    $('nav ul').removeClass('showing');
});
```

I also noticed your HTML structure is wrong...
The *<li>* should be child of *<ul>*

```
 <nav>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="handle">Menu</div>
 </nav>
```

Working fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/osd4nn1n/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works but it has a strange behavior when it closes.

Comment: Can I see it somewhere?

Comment: No, It's just a practice site I'm playing with, its not uploaded anywhere.The solutions works just fine and could be used but it almost has a pause before it closes.

Comment: Actually I just gave it another try and works just fine. Nvm, Thank you.

Comment: Don't worry! The important thing is that you have the solution! Cheers!